AWS CloudFormation: How to create aws budget with multiple emails
I have a cloudformation template like this:
  Parameters:
    EmailList:
      Type: String
  
  Resources:
      Budget:
        Type: AWS::Budgets::Budget
        Properties:
          Budget:
            BudgetName: "my-test-budget"
          NotificationsWithSubscribers:
            - Notification:
                NotificationType: !Ref NotificationType
                ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
                Threshold: !Ref WarningThreshold
              Subscribers:
                Address: !Ref EmailList

Here the EmailList is array of emailIds searated by comma(e.g: abc@gmail.com,hello123@gmail.com), hence cannot use !Ref EmailList directly, If I split the EmailList and assign it to Address
Address: !Split [",", !Ref EmailList] this is not working, as Address field is expecting only one email Id to be assigned at once.
Since EmailList is a user provided emails, splitting by index o(i.e. Address: !Select [0, !Split [",", !Ref EmailList]]) wouldn't be helpful as this assigns only 0th emailId to Address, also, will not be knowing exactly how many email ids will be provided.
How can we split and assign each emailId to Address field individually?

Note that CommaDelimitedList is a valid parameter type in CloudFormation.

Is it an option in your case to create a single distribution group for these email addresses?

Also, it looks like Parameteres might be misspelled.

@jarmod, but AWS is expecting to provide the email id's individually but not as comma delimited values, hence split and assign does not not. If I read EmailList as CommaDelimitedList then that cant be Split eitherm right?

I'd hope that using CommaDelimitedList in combination with Fn::ForEach (requiring Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions) would allow you to iterate over the email values and emit subscriber template fragments for each. If you have time to investigate, see if that helps. Forewarned that this is not an area of strength for CloudFormation, in my opinion.
